# Devexpress datagrid vertical scroll

Tags: datagrid, scroll, devexpress

I have a problem with vertical scroll. Though in options I set it to auto (also checked always), and set columns best fit, vertical scroll doesn't appear so I get limited width size. How can I enable vertical scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it myself by setting ColumnAutoWidth option to False.